# Finer control on battery running out and having to recharge it

Tags: notifications, battery, charging, battery-life, battery-saver

Using a smartphone is nowadays vital to work.

When my battery reaches 2%, a notification, from the bottom of the screen (this, was well thought. The battery, and battery charger is on the bottom, so it is very well that the message is from the bottom), triggers off.

However, I would like it if you could program both the trigger, for when the battery message were to come up, as well as the time intervals of possible successive warnings of when to remind to charge the phone. These, must have defaults, for instance:

- I may choose to trigger the charge battery alarm at 40%

  - And subsequently every 5% of discharge.
  - Or subsequently every five, ten, twenty, or forty minutes.

You should be able to configure this in the settings.

This would help me in situations where I am walking outside not far from home, in which I would return, within forty minutes.

In these cases, I should also be able to turn the reminder for the battery off. I may just want to have the phone on until it drags out all the battery. Or I may want to turn the warning off, turn on the phone, and then turn it back on just before a phone call is expected, or just before needed.

...

But, because, sometimes I may go out of home for a short time, sometimes for a long time, sometimes I may be out driving, or sometimes you may be at a day center, or in an office, or at the dentist or to the doctor's, and more time may be required (silencing may override the battery warning),...

Because of this, you might want to be able to override these settings in the battery warning notification that shows up.

For instance, just as with alarms, for appointments and meetings, you may want to specify a specific battery discharge interval or time warning interval before dismissing (or even set a specific one, overriding the settings, and then dismiss).

For instance, you may be in a car, and your friend Matt be already using the car charger and you do not have a USB hub in your car, so you cannot plug in your phone as well, and in this case you may want to postpone, say, two hours, so that you will know the prompt to charge your phone may kick off when you are at home, where, hopefully, everyone has a charger. And if even there a charger is missing, because, perhaps, over broke and they are all in use, then you can use the same battery discharging prompt to set the next battery (perhaps your companion is using theirs while hooked up to USB but you just care that your phone will not run out of battery because you are expecting an important phone call, so will choose a percentage drain parameter instead of a time drain parameter).

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but your question is bit long to read it fully, and the used sentences are also very long (the last section are only two sentences). In the end you are searching for an app that has a very flexible battery notification system. What apps from Play Store have you tested so far?